# Removing the last child node DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to create a page with two different sides, and to that end I have set up in two different divs with IDs of `leftSide` and `rightSide`.

Firstly, I add an image node to `leftSide` five times.

Then, I clone `leftSide` to the `rightSide` div, and I want to remove the last image from `rightSide` so that, in total, I have five images on the left and four images on the right.

However, my code just deletes all five images on the left side, not just the last one:

```
function createSmile() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        newImg.src = "smile.png";
        var imgPart = document.getElementById("leftSide");
        imgPart.appendChild(newImg);
    }

    document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(document.getElementById("leftSide").cloneNode(true));

    document.getElementById("rightSide").removeChild(document.getElementById("rightSide").lastChild);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clone `#leftSide` into `#rightSide`, so `#rightSide` has only one children. and then you delete last from only one children.

Solution is here

```
function createSmile() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        newImg.src = "smile.png";

        leftSide.appendChild(newImg);
        rightSide.appendChild(newImg.cloneNode(true));
    }

    //Here you clone WHOLE <div id="leftSide"></div> into <div id="rightSide"></div>
    //document.getElementById("rightSide").appendChild(document.getElementById("leftSide").cloneNode(true));

    rightSide.removeChild(rightSide.lastChild);

}
```

Comment: While this answer does explain what OP's problem is, it doesn't give any solutions as to what he can do about it. Please take a look at StackOverflow's guide to answering questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

This happened because rightSide has only one child which is the clone of leftSide. So you are removing child but what you haveto do is remove grandchild.

Consider using this:

```
document.getElementById("rightSide").removeChild(document.getElementById("rightSide").children[0].lastChild);
```

Hope that works
It would also be better if you look at the source code of your html from Google Chrome to understand what javascript produced

Comment: You would still end up with a second div with the ID of `leftSide` using this solution, which would not be good if OP wants to reference that element again in JS. It is better to address the root of the problem, how the elements are being cloned in the first place.

Comment: Yes you are right. There would be id confusion. Cloning process should be revisited

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

When you clone a node, you clone it's entire block of HTML. For example, when you clone `leftSide` and append it into `rightSide`, what you are appending really is this:

```
<div id="leftSide">
    <img src="smile.png">
    <img src="smile.png">
    <img src="smile.png">
    <img src="smile.png">
    <img src="smile.png">
</div>
```

Note that the `leftSide` div got copied in there as well? Not only is this bad because you now have two elements with the same ID, but also now there is only one child node, that div, which then contains all of the images.

### What can we do about it?

Essentially what you want is to copy only the child nodes of `leftSide`. There are numerous ways to go about doing this:

- If you are using something such as jQuery, you can use `$("#leftSide").children().clone()` to clone all of the child elements;
- You could get the array of child nodes (`document.getElementById("leftSide").childNodes`), loop through it, and clone each one;
- You could simply add the image nodes to both of the divs in your initial loop;
- You could also copy the raw internal HTML across: `document.getElementById("rightSide").innerHTML = document.getElementById("leftSide").innerHTML`

These are only some of the ways you could solve this. There are many more on [Google](https://google.com/search?q=clone%20children%20of%20an%20element%20js).